# How to submit a custom html form in Typo3 page

Tags: php, html, forms, typo3

Is there a way to submit your own custom html form and have typo3 email it?

I want to avoid using the inbuilt form creator and code my own form, I just need to know how I would go about submitting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from coding it completely yourself, you could also use the extension "Formhandler". ([Link](http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/formhandler/))

It will allow you to Add your own HTML to fluid templates and handle all the sending etc. for you. Depending on the complexity of the form the code it yourself solution might be easier.

Comment: This looks interesting I will look into it. But what if I wanted the form to be written directly in the html template file? Would I need to incorporate a php mail function in there somewhere? typo3 doesn't seem to allow the upload of php files... (I am a typo3 novice, forgive me if these sound like stupid questions)

Comment: No you wouldn't need to do that, formhandler takes care of this. You define alle the settings in the typoscript that is related to the form. But you can upload your own PHP in T3, but it works a little different and is called a "user function" (best google that). For Formhandler, best download one of the demo forms and look how it is made to check if it is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create custom extension with frontend plugin. The easiest way to start is to install the [**Extension Builder**](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) ext.

For rendering the HTML view of the mail you can use [**StandaloneView**](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_fluid_1_1_view_1_1_standalone_view.html)

For sending mails you can use the [**Mail API**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html)